# Redux Pagination with filtered data

Tags: reactjs, search, redux, pagination

I make a search app and I want to add a pagination. Till now , after search I display the results in new component. The app is small (approx. 4-5 results max from search) but I want to make a pagination for bigger data. Whats the best way to do it with redux ?

Comment: Will you send a page query param to the server or will your client fetch all data and paginate on the client?

Comment: I take the whole list from server and after I do filtering according to params on the client side. Like from 20 object for search param {title:"java"} it returns me 4 objects that includes title with "Java" word. and then I use those data to a new component , but I want to paginate those 4 results (in case I have much larger data in the future)

Comment: If you have all the data and filter/paginate on the client then you can use [selectors](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) to do that